# imageview movement in relative layout

Tags: android

I am trying to make a splash screen which has got 2 images .1st one is at center and moves up, 2nd one comes in when 1st goes up completely.
I have done the animation for the 1st image but the second one is not working in the desired manner. Actually I am not quite sure do i use imageswitcher or any other function. Please let me know what shall i do.
I would share the codes here.

```
public class Splash_screen extends Activity { // SPLASH ACTIVITY

       @Override

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

           ImageView kfcpic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.kfclogo);
           ImageView sogood= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sogood);


           TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-500); //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
           animation.setDuration(3000);  // animation duration
           //animation.setRepeatCount(0);  // animation repeat count
           animation.setRepeatMode(1);
           animation.setFillAfter(true);
           // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
           //animation.setFillAfter(true);

           kfcpic.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation


        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash_screen.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                        }
                    });



                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    finish();
                }
            }

        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }
    }
```

Comment: For the second image you can define a start offset for animation or attach an animation listener to the first animation for the end anim callback. What have you tried till now?

Comment: @Override
                       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                           sogood.startAnimation(animation2);

                       }

Comment: I tried adding a listener and did this but again the 1st image is only moving  , 2nd does  not appears

Comment: Just confirming: Did you set the above listener to the animation object before calling `startAnimation()`?

Comment: Well I guess I did that, see,

Comment: animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                       }

                       @ Override
                       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                           sogood.startAnimation(animation2);

Comment: Alright, let me try to reproduce the issue on my end

Comment: @Shaishav  I think its done now..the prob was not in java file, it was in xml, t eh srcCompat was holding @drawable/sogood , i cut paste this to backgroud column, it shows up now. !!

Comment: Cool...btw you may replace your `Thread` code with a `Handler`

Comment: I would definitely do that in nxt project :) n btw on 2nd image .setVisible isnt woking , I want it to be visible after onAnimationEnd() method..suggestions ?

Comment: I guess i  did it too :) i probably should stop asking so many questions.. ;)

Comment: btw Thanks a lot for your time , means lot to me @Shaishav

Comment: Since, you are using hardcoded animation params, I think the issue is that the views end up outside its parent layout container bounds. Try setting `android:clipChildren=false` on the layout parents (and their parents too if required) of the image views.

Comment: Cool...happy coding

Comment: Btw, if you want, you can replace your `Thread` code with `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash_screen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 3000);`

Comment: thanks, I would try that too, and also if u can let me know how to move these iamges faster?

Comment: Get rid of animation listener and in your animation2: `animation2.setStartOffset(1000);`. Now simply call `startAnimation()` on both your imageviews together.

Comment: well, it did not moved it fast, but interpolator did the job...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't set the visibility of *sogood* ImageView correctly. It would be better if you could provide the layout of this SplashActivity.

Comment: I was giving the incorrect params , got it rit,,,sille me at times :)

Comment: BTW, if you can tell me how to move it faster ? the 2nd image view ?

Comment: you can shorten the duration, for example: `animation.setDuration(3000);`. Do you mean this?